# Kylin: Datasource tab is disabled

Tags: kylin

Going thru this tutorial: http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/tutorial/create_cube.html

But the 'Data Source' tab under 'Model' is disabled. I am logged in as ADMIN. What am I doing wrong? Did I miss a step? I do have the following tables in Hive:

```
hive> show tables;
OK
kylin_cal_dt
kylin_category_groupings
kylin_sales
sample_07
sample_08
```

Comment: Have you sync the tables into Kylin? Also try reload Kylin metadata from the 'System' panel.

Comment: I must have missed some step or something. I tried with a latest version & got past this issue. Thanks.